# AutoCompleteTextView com palavras acentuadas

Tags: java, android

Estou com uma certa dificuldade para usar o AutoCompleteTextView com palavras acentuadas.

Por exemplo:

Estou buscando nomes de agências bancarias, ao digitar somente `ita` o banco Itaú é encontrando, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, se eu digitar o último `u` da palavra `Itaú` sem o acento, o autocomplete já não o encontra mais, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de ignorar essas acentuações e encontrar colocando ou não o texto com acentos?

**Obs:** Eu já estou fazendo com custom adapter, que implementa **Filterable**

Segue abaixo o código do custom adapter:

```
public class HRArrayAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {


        private List<T> mObjects;
        private final Object mLock = new Object();
        private int mResource;
        private int mFieldId = 0;

        private boolean mNotifyOnChange = true;

        private Context mContext;

        private ArrayList<T> mOriginalValues;
        private HRArrayFilter mFilter;

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;


        public HRArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            init(context, textViewResourceId, 0, new ArrayList<T>());
        }


        public HRArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
            init(context, resource, textViewResourceId, new ArrayList<T>());
        }


        public HRArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
            init(context, textViewResourceId, 0, Arrays.asList(objects));
        }


        public HRArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
            init(context, resource, textViewResourceId, Arrays.asList(objects));
        }


        public HRArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
            init(context, textViewResourceId, 0, objects);
        }


        public HRArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
            init(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }


        public void add(T object) {
            if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    mOriginalValues.add(object);
                    if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                mObjects.add(object);
                if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }


        public void insert(T object, int index) {
            if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    mOriginalValues.add(index, object);
                    if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                mObjects.add(index, object);
                if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }


        public void remove(T object) {
            if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    mOriginalValues.remove(object);
                }
            } else {
                mObjects.remove(object);
            }
            if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        public void clear() {
            if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    mOriginalValues.clear();
                }
            } else {
                mObjects.clear();
            }
            if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        public void sort(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
            Collections.sort(mObjects, comparator);
            if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mNotifyOnChange = true;
        }


        public void setNotifyOnChange(boolean notifyOnChange) {
            mNotifyOnChange = notifyOnChange;
        }

        private void init(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
            mContext = context;
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mResource = mDropDownResource = resource;
            mObjects = objects;
            mFieldId = textViewResourceId;
        }


        public Context getContext() {
            return mContext;
        }


        public int getCount() {
            return mObjects.size();
        }


        public T getItem(int position) {
            return mObjects.get(position);
        }


        public int getPosition(T item) {
            return mObjects.indexOf(item);
        }


        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);
        }

        private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent,
                                            int resource) {
            View view;
            TextView text;

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }

            try {
                if (mFieldId == 0) {
                    //  If no custom field is assigned, assume the whole resource is a TextView
                    text = (TextView) view;
                } else {
                    //  Otherwise, find the TextView field within the layout
                    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(mFieldId);
                }
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                Log.e("ArrayAdapter", "You must supply a resource ID for a TextView");
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView", e);
            }

            text.setText(getItem(position).toString());

            return view;
        }


        public void setDropDownViewResource(int resource) {
            this.mDropDownResource = resource;
        }


        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mDropDownResource);
        }


        public static HRArrayAdapter<CharSequence> createFromResource(Context context,
                                                                                 int textArrayResId, int textViewResId) {
            CharSequence[] strings = context.getResources().getTextArray(textArrayResId);
            return new HRArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context, textViewResId, strings);
        }


        public HRArrayFilter getFilter() {
            if (mFilter == null) {
                mFilter = new HRArrayFilter();
            }
            return mFilter;
        }


        private class HRArrayFilter extends Filter {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    synchronized (mLock) {
                        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<T>(mObjects);
                    }
                }

                if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                    synchronized (mLock) {
                        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(mOriginalValues);
                        results.values = list;
                        results.count = list.size();
                    }
                } else {
                    String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                    ArrayList<T> values = mOriginalValues;
                    final int count = values.size();

                    final ArrayList<T> newValues = new ArrayList<T>(count);
                    final ArrayList<String> strippedAccents = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        final T value = values.get(i);
                        final String valueText = value.toString().toLowerCase();
                        String valueTextNoPalatals = stripAccents(valueText);
                        String prefixStringNoPalatals = stripAccents(prefixString);

                        // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                        if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString) || valueTextNoPalatals.startsWith(prefixStringNoPalatals)) {
                            newValues.add(value);
                        } else {
                            final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
                            final int wordCount = words.length;

                            for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                                if (words[k].startsWith(prefixString)) {
                                    newValues.add(value);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    results.values = newValues;
                    results.count = newValues.size();
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                //noinspection unchecked
                mObjects = (List<T>) results.values;
                if (results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        }

        private static Map<Character, Character> MAP_NORM;
        private static String stripAccents(String value) {

            if (MAP_NORM == null || MAP_NORM.size() == 0)
            {
                MAP_NORM = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
                MAP_NORM.put('À', 'A');
                MAP_NORM.put('Á', 'A');
                MAP_NORM.put('Â', 'A');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ã', 'A');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ä', 'A');
                MAP_NORM.put('È', 'E');
                MAP_NORM.put('É', 'E');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ê', 'E');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ë', 'E');
                MAP_NORM.put('Í', 'I');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ì', 'I');
                MAP_NORM.put('Î', 'I');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ï', 'I');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ù', 'U');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ú', 'U');
                MAP_NORM.put('Û', 'U');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ü', 'U');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ò', 'O');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ó', 'O');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ô', 'O');
                MAP_NORM.put('Õ', 'O');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ö', 'O');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ñ', 'N');
                MAP_NORM.put('Ç', 'C');
                MAP_NORM.put('ª', 'A');
                MAP_NORM.put('º', 'O');
                MAP_NORM.put('§', 'S');
                MAP_NORM.put('³', '3');
                MAP_NORM.put('²', '2');
                MAP_NORM.put('¹', '1');
                MAP_NORM.put('à', 'a');
                MAP_NORM.put('á', 'a');
                MAP_NORM.put('â', 'a');
                MAP_NORM.put('ã', 'a');
                MAP_NORM.put('ä', 'a');
                MAP_NORM.put('è', 'e');
                MAP_NORM.put('é', 'e');
                MAP_NORM.put('ê', 'e');
                MAP_NORM.put('ë', 'e');
                MAP_NORM.put('í', 'i');
                MAP_NORM.put('ì', 'i');
                MAP_NORM.put('î', 'i');
                MAP_NORM.put('ï', 'i');
                MAP_NORM.put('ù', 'u');
                MAP_NORM.put('ú', 'u');
                MAP_NORM.put('û', 'u');
                MAP_NORM.put('ü', 'u');
                MAP_NORM.put('ò', 'o');
                MAP_NORM.put('ó', 'o');
                MAP_NORM.put('ô', 'o');
                MAP_NORM.put('õ', 'o');
                MAP_NORM.put('ö', 'o');
                MAP_NORM.put('ñ', 'n');
                MAP_NORM.put('ç', 'c');
            }

            if (value == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value);

            for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
                Character c = MAP_NORM.get(sb.charAt(i));
                if(c != null) {
                    sb.setCharAt(i, c.charValue());
                }
            }

            return sb.toString();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda: [Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3322152/1964435)

Comment: Valeu Math! Desculpa pela demora na resposta, mas me ajudou sim! Era só usar o *java.text.Normalizer*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de fazer a comparação você pode retirar os acentos da String do seu AutoCompleteTextView no método `performFiltering()`, usando por exemplo o Normalizer:

```
System.out.println(Normalizer
                    .normalize("Itaú", Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                    .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")
                   );
```

Resultado:

> Itau

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/gfAmHu).

Fonte: [Is there a way to get rid of accents and convert a whole string to regular letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3322152/1964435)